# Iterating over a list to check if numbers are consecutive

Tags: c#, console

The goal of the code is to take a string of numbers separated by hyphens and check if they are consecutive.
I have tried using string.spit, iterating over the array and checking if the number +1 is equal to the next value. But I've run into an issue of the index I'm working on exceeding the bounds of the array.
Here is the current build.

```
public static void Consecutive()
    {
        Console.Write("enter multiple numbers separated by hyphens: ");
        var userinput = Console.ReadLine();
        
        var nums = userinput.Split();
        
        int index = 0;
        bool isConsecutive = false;

        foreach(var number in nums)
        {
            if(Convert.ToInt32(nums[index + 1]) == Convert.ToInt32(nums[index] + 1))
            {
                isConsecutive = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isConsecutive = false;
            }
            if(index == nums.Length)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(isConsecutive);
    }
```

Comment: Code fails when you are on last item (var number in nums) because you are indexing  one more item than list.  Change From : index == nums.Length To: index == nums.Length - 1

Comment: ^^ + `Convert.ToInt32(nums[index] + 1)` this will not do what you expect.

Comment: Also: You never **change** `index`. So all you'll ever do is compare `nums[1]` to something that you don't expect.

Comment: Regarding `Convert.ToInt32(nums[index] + 1)` : https://dotnetfiddle.net/zhDzGr

Comment: _"separated by hyphens"_ you dont split by hyphens

Comment: Also: If everything else worked as expected and you had the input "1-3-4" your output would be "true" because the second check would hide the first one. If you find one inconsecutive element, the whole thing is not consecutive, so bail out.

Comment: Also, the other people are correct, but nobody has yet mentioned that if a single number was entered, there'd be no need to do a comparison and you cannot really evaluate if isConsecutive should be true or false. You could determine your own rule to say it's false, but it may be better to say 2 or more numbers are required.

Comment: It would be better to ensure your user input gets validated and becomes a ```List<int>``` and to only iterate it when the number of elements it has is >=2, then use a for loop that goes from index 1 through to count-1.

Comment: And on the validation subject, you don't want to fall foul of user input such as ```-4``` or ```12-``` where simply splitting on the hypen will seek to give 2 elements when you only really have 1. A regular expression may be best to validate the user input.

Comment: `-3, −2, −1, 0, 1, 2, 3` is considered consecutive. The hyphen is a really poor choice of delimiter!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to split by hyphens, but you split by white-spaces. You also don't use the `number` loop variable of the `foreach`. For what you are doing a `for`-loop is much more appropriate anyway:

```
public static void Consecutive()
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter multiple numbers separated by hyphens: ");
    string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] nums = userinput.Split('-');
    // always validate input
    while (!nums.All(n => n.All(char.IsDigit)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All numbers must be valid integers");
        userinput = Console.ReadLine();
        nums = userinput.Split('-');
    }

    bool isConsecutive = true;
    for(int i = 1; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        int thisInt = int.Parse(nums[i]);
        int prevInt = int.Parse(nums[i - 1]);
        if(thisInt != prevInt + 1)
        {
            isConsecutive = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(isConsecutive);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when the `foreach` loop iterates over the last element there is no element with `index + 1` and your check `if(index == nums.Length)` does not work.

**Explanation:**

nums.Length = last index + 1.

For an array with 5 elements, the length = 5 and the last index = 4.

Because of that your if condition is never `true`.

**Solution:**

Change the condition from `if(index == nums.Length)` to `if(index == nums.Length - 1)`

Comment: _"Because of that your if condition is never true."_ - It also never going to be true, because OP does not mutate `index`. The line is equivalent to `if(0 == nums.Length)` right now.

Comment: Correct, and it seems like OP does not use the `number` variable from the `foreach`. [Here is a reference on C# iterations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach, generating the expected sequence and seeing if that matches the cleansed input:

```
var delimiter = ",";
Console.Write("Enter multiple integers separated by '" + delimiter + "': ");
var userinput = Console.ReadLine(); ;

bool isConsecutive = false;
try
{
    var strNums = userinput.Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());
    var nums = Array.ConvertAll(strNums, x => int.Parse(x));
    var consecutive = Enumerable.Range(nums[0], nums.Length);

    var strCleansed = String.Join(delimiter, nums);
    var strGenerated = String.Join(delimiter, consecutive);
    isConsecutive = (strCleansed == strGenerated);

    Console.WriteLine("    cleansed = " + strCleansed);
    Console.WriteLine("   generated = " + strGenerated);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Integer in Input");
}

Console.WriteLine("isConsecutive = " + isConsecutive);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Sample runs:

```
Enter multiple integers separated by ',': -3, -0000002,         -1,       0, 1, 02,   3
    cleansed = -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3
   generated = -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3
isConsecutive = True

Enter multiple integers separated by ',': 1,2,3,5
    cleansed = 1,2,3,5
   generated = 1,2,3,4
isConsecutive = False

Enter multiple integers separated by ',': 1,fish,2,fish,red fish,blue fish
Invalid Integer in Input
isConsecutive = False
```